# buidling matplotlib with Tkinter OSX

Tags: python, macos, build, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to build Matplotlib from source with Tkinter.

OSX version 10.9.2

Here is what I have done:

Built tcl8.6 and tk8.6 with configure/make/make install

Built python2.7.6 with configure/make/make install

When I try to build Matplotlib it builds properly except it won't include (build against) Tkinter:

I get this message:

> OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
>
> ```
>              libpng: 1.6.9
>            Tkinter: no
>                     * Tkinter present, but header files are not found.
>                     * You may need to install development packages.
> ```

Why can't it find the Tkinter headers or does it need tk.h?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to build it all from source yourself?  There are binary installers out there and third-party package managers for OS X.

Comment: I am interested in Matplotlib source code.  Building allows me to play with it.  Now, I want to turn on TkAgg.

Comment: You still can do that without having to build Python itself.  It can all be tricky to get everything right. Be aware that the Tk 8.6.1 source release is missing a critical fix for OS X 10.9.x last time I checked.  You might want to just use the ActiveTcl binaries which have the fix.  (See https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ and http://bugs.python.org/issue19373)

Comment: It looks like that fix is in.  I just need to know how to tell Python about the location of the tcl/tk headers I think. This can be done without having to fall back on pulling binaries.  I can build Matplotlib fine, its just not linking with tkinter properly.